# Reading strings from JSON using ksh

Tags: shell, ksh

```
{

  "assignedTo": [

    "Daniel Raisor",
    "Dalton Leslie",
    "Logan Petro"  
]

}
```

I want to extract Daniel Raisor Dalton Leslie and Logan Petro and assign these to a separate variable like assignedTo=Daniel Raisor,Dalton Leslie,Logan Petro
also my unix doesn't support jq ,I need to do this using grep or sed command

Comment: If you need to work with JSON, you need to get a tool that works with JSON; `grep` et al. do not. Also, not having `jq` pre-installed does not necessarily mean `jq` is not supported; it is quite portable and easy to install.

Comment: `grep` or `sed` can't parse JSON reliably. You can come up with an awful hack that uses them, but it'll be a *hack*, and it'll be fragile -- as in, changes in the encoding or content that don't have anything to do with the syntax will be able to break it.

Comment: By contrast -- do you have a Python interpreter available? It's very easy to call through to Python from shell, and use the built-in JSON-parsing module there.

Comment: Be sure to check whether your solution will work with different whitespace -- ie. `{"assignedTo":["Daniel Raisor","Dalton Leslie","Logan Petro"]}` all on one line. Or *extra* newlines put in in random places. Or a name with quotes like `"Logan \"The Man\" Wilson"`.

Comment: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). Consider some of these when trying to decide which characters couldn't possibly be part of a name, and thus can be used to separate two names from each other.

Answer (score 1):

Use a proper JSON parser to parse JSON. Even if you don't have `jq`, there's a perfectly good one included with the Python interpreter, which the following example script uses:

```sh
#!/bin/ksh
# note: this was tested with ksh93u+ 2012-08-01
# to use with Python 3 rather than Python 2, replace "pipes" with "shlex"

json='{"assignedTo": ["Daniel \"The Man\" Raisor","Dalton Leslie","Logan Petro"]}'

getEntries() {
  python -c '
import json, sys, pipes

content = json.load(sys.stdin)
for name, values in content.iteritems():
  print("%s=%s" % (pipes.quote(name), pipes.quote(",".join(values))))
'
}

eval "$(getEntries <<<"$json")"
echo "$assignedTo"
```

...properly emits the following output:

```
Daniel "The Man" Raisor,Dalton Leslie,Logan Petro
```